# How can I use SVM classifier for my Keras model?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, classification, svm

I am working on predicting seizure epilepsy using CNN. I have 2 classes in my dataset. I want to use CNN model as a feature extractor, then I want to use SVM as a classifier. I don't know how to do this with my model.

I am using mode.fit_generator in my model and I don't have X and y because I use generator for my data. How can I use the traditional SVM for my model? Any help would be appreciated.

```
    model.add(Conv2D(32, ( 3, 3), strides=(1,1), padding='same',  activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=32,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.6))  
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.6))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.6))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    opt_adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(loss=categorical_focal_loss(), optimizer=opt_adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, train_data, start=0,end=100), 
                                validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, test_data, start=0,end=100),
                                steps_per_epoch=int((len(train_data)/2)), 
                                validation_steps=int((len(test_data)/2)),
                                verbose=2,epochs=65, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True)
```

I want to make SVM classifier as my final classifier in this model so how can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.